# Visual Studio 2010 Linker Finding Multiply Defined Symbols (Where It Shouldn't)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I've just started with C++, and maybe there's something that I'm doing wrong here, but I'm at a loss. When I try to build the solution, I get 4 `LNK2005` errors like this one:

`error LNK2005: "public: double __thiscall Point::GetX(void)const " (?GetX@Point@@QBENXZ) already defined in CppSandbox.obj`

(there's one for each get/set method, and they all allegedly occur in `Point.obj`)

And then finally this error:

`error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Which reportedly occurs in `CppSandbox.exe`. I'm not sure what causes this error - it appears to happen when I build or rebuild the solution... Really at a loss, to be honest.

The three files below are the entirety of what I added to the default VS2010 blank project (they're copied in their entirety). Thanks for any help you can offer.

**Point.h**

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point() 
    { 
        x = 0; 
        y = 0; 
    };
    Point(double xv, double yv) 
    { 
        x = xv;
        y = yv; 
    };

    double GetX() const;
    void SetX(double nval);

    double GetY() const;
    void SetY(double nval);

    bool operator==(const Point &other)
    {
        return GetX() == other.GetX() && GetY() == other.GetY();
    }

    bool operator!=(const Point &other)
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

**Point.cpp**

```
#include "Point.h"

double Point::GetX() const
{
    return x;
}

double Point::GetY() const
{
    return y;
}

void Point::SetX(double nv)
{
    x = nv;
}

void Point::SetY(double nv)
{
    y = nv;
}
```

**CppSandbox.cpp**

```
// CppSandbox.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.cpp"

int main()
{
    Point p(1, 2);
    Point q(1, 2);
    Point r(2, 3);

    if (p == q) std::cout << "P == Q";
    if (q == p) std::cout << "Equality is commutative";
    if (p == r || q == r) std::cout << "Equality is broken";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in **CppSandbox.cpp**:

```
#include "Point.cpp"
```

You are including the cpp file instead of the header file, so its contents are compiled twice and everything in it is therefore defined twice.  (It's compiled once when **Point.cpp** is compiled, and a second time when **CppSandbox.cpp** is compiled.)

You should include the header file in **CppSandbox.cpp**:

```
#include "Point.h"
```

Your header file should also have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: That fixed it, and I've added the include guards. Thanks for your help